# How to understand the definition of Markov Chain $P(X_{n+1}\in B\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=p(X_n,B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process, transition-matrix

The definition of Markov Chain in Durrett ([Probability: Theory and Examples](https://amzn.to/3SuHzWg), 2019, Section 5.2) is:

$$P(X_{n+1}\in B\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=p(X_n,B), $$

where $p$ is the Markov transition kernel distribution and $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the filtration induced by the sequence $(X_n)_n$.

My earlier exposure to Markov chains is associated with the property
$$P(X_{n+1}=x\mid X_n=x_n)=P(X_{n+1}=x\mid X_{n-1}=x_{n-1},X_n=x_n).$$

What is the intuition behind the first definition and are those two definition equivalent?

Comment: Hello. Complete citation would be appreciated.

Comment: @User1865345 This definition seems the first definition in Section 5.2 of *Probability: Theory and Examples* (2019 version) by Durrett.

Comment: Thanks @Zhanxiong. OP miswrote the author's name. That's what I wanted to confirm. And importantly, complete citation is always helpful.

Comment: Durrett's definition is the general one for Markov chain (i.e., the underlying state space of the stochastic process can be either continuous or discrete), while the definition you "learned" applies to discrete-state space chain only, which is normally given in an elementary probability course.  If you have some knowledge of measure-theoretic conditional probability, you can easily verify that the first definition subsumes the second one.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, also the equations are flipped, i.e. the left hand side of the first one is the generalization of the right hand side in second equation and vice versa.

Comment: @LukasLohse I can understand that the LHS of the first equation is similar to the RHS of the second equation. But how to prove that the RHS of the second equation is similar to the LHS of the second one?

Comment: Usually $p(x_n, B) = P(X_{n+1} \in B | X_n = x_n)$, now writing $p(X_n, B) = P(X_{n+1} \in B | X_n)$ is a sensible "extrapolation of notation" and it takes care of having to add the whole "for all possible values of $x_n$" bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, Durrett could have provided a better mechanism for the generalization, albeit being correct.

$\rm [I]$ does provide a more extensive treatment:

Let $(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, \Pr) $ be a probability space; let the range $E$ be a Polish space equipped with $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_E,~I\subset\mathbb R $ an index set. Consider then the $E$-valued stochastic process $X:=\langle X_t\rangle_{t\in I}.$ Let $\mathfrak F^X_t$ be the filtration generated by $X.$

Then $X$ follows Markov Property if for all $A\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_E, $

$$\Pr[X_t\in A\mid \mathfrak F_s]=\Pr[X_t\in A\mid X_s],~~s,t\in I\wedge s\leq t\tag{MP}\label 1.$$

This is the general definition of Markov property. We would show that when $E$ is a countable space, then $\eqref 1$ implies the more familiar form that OP cited.

Now let $i, i_1, \ldots, i_n\in E$ and $ s_1< \ldots< s_n<t.$ Take $A:=\{\omega\in\Omega: X_{s_1}=i_1,\ldots, X_{s_n}=i_n\}.$ Therefore

\begin{align}\Pr[\{X_t=i\}\cap A]&=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{\{X_t=i\}}\mid \mathfrak F_{s_n}]\mathbf 1_A]\\&=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{\{X_t=i\}}\mid  X_{s_n}]\mathbf 1_A]\\&=\mathbb E[\Pr[X_t=i\mid  X_{s_n}=i_n]\mathbf 1_A]\\&=\Pr[X_t=i\mid  X_{s_n}=i_n]\Pr[A]\tag 1,\label 2\end{align} where the first equality is due to the definition of conditional expectation, the second equality is due to $\eqref 1$ and the third one being due to the fact that when $\bigsqcup_{i\in I}B_i=\Omega,$ then $\mathbb E[X\mid\sigma(B_i)](\omega)=\mathbb E[X\mid B_i]\iff B_i\ni\omega~\textrm{a.s.}$

Now dividing both sides of $\eqref 2$ by $\Pr[A]$ (assuming it to be greater than $0, $ of course), we get

$$\Pr[X_t=i\mid X_{s_1}=i_1, \ldots, X_{s_n}=i_n]=\Pr[X_t=i\mid X_{s_n}=i_n].$$

Time-homogeneous Markov property can then be defined in terms of the stochastic kernel, as has been done in $\rm[ I].$

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course, *Achim Klenke,* Springer, $2020, $ sec. $17.1, $ pp. $391-392.$

Comment: +1 for the generality.  I agree with you that Durrett seems to make an originally quite intuitive concept a little more convoluted by introducing another concept (i.e., transition kernel) in the basic Markov property definition (he could have just defined it as $P(X_{n + 1} \in B | \mathcal{F}_n) = P(X_{n + 1} \in B | X_n)$).  When I got time, I would provide an answer that is based on Billingsley's treatment.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Good point! I think Durrett is definition is good for qual exams: we only need to memorize one equation for two concepts.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, Durrett's definition is a general definition of the Markov property in an underlying discrete-time stochastic process, whereas the definition you have given is a type of framing of the Markov property in the special case of a discrete-time discrete-state-space process.

The intuition behind the Durrett equation is as follows (taking $n$ as the "present" time).  The filtration $F_n$ gives you the whole history of the process up to the present time $n$, whereas $X_n$ only gives the state of the process at the present time $n$.  The Durrett equation says that when you condition on the filtration (i.e., the entire history up to the present time) then the resulting conditional probability $X_{n+1} \in B$ for the next state of the process can be written as a function only of the space $B$ and the value $X_n$ at the present time.  In other words, the conditional probability of the next state given the entire history of the process up to the present only depends on the part of the history that is the state of the process at the present time value.  This is the [Markov property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) which defines a Markov chain.